# Использовать layout активити первого, вторым активити

Tags: java, android

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Как лучше организовать переключение.
Есть расходы и доходы. 
Думал сделать переключение  через listview.setVisibility
Но геморойна ввиду кучи хлама в одном активити
Разделил на два активити  доходы и расходы. 
Но получилось что, дублирующий тебе кнопки, новый оброботчик. 
И получает при переключение все моргает, обновляется на новый layout.
Думал сделать listview один на один наложить со свойство visibility, а при втором активити использовать layout первого активити,но переключать visibility. Это является адекватным и правильным решением?

Comment: Для такого паттерна есть TabLayout и ViewPager. То что вы напридумывали не только не адекватное и не правильное решение, а какой то треш. Почему бы вам вместо того, чтобы мучить себя поисками собственных путей в том, что давно придумано, не почитать книжку по разработке (например Б.Филлипса или П.Дейтела) и тратить время на, собственно, разработку, а не придумывание адских конструкций.

Answer (score 0):

В данном случае, лучше использовать фрагменты (Fragment), вы же не будете для каждого экрана создавать новые Activity. С фрагментами и приложение будет работать правильно и Вам проблем в дальнейшем меньше будет.

Comment: А вот я фрагменты терпеть не могу, от них точно проблем меньше не будет. Например, при повороте экрана у вас будет пересозданный не присоединенный к активити фрагмент. Я бы сделал это без фрагментов все в одной активити.

Comment: Проблемы при повороте легко решаются, что значит "я терпеть не могу" человек спрашивает как правильно сделать, а не как Вам нравится.

Comment: Не мне одному они не нравятся [https://habrahabr.ru/post/277289/](https://habrahabr.ru/post/277289/)

Comment: Неубедительно, раз Google рекомендует использовать фрагменты, значит это некий сложившийся стандарт, а то что непонятно кто отказался от фрагментов и рекомендует так делать всем, ничего не значит. В любом случае каждый выбирает то, что ему больше подходит.